# Why is chromedriver failing with ruby 2.4.0 and bundler 2.0.1 with undefined method `[]' for nil:NilClass (NoMethodError)

Tags: ruby, capybara

i am trying to run my ruby app which uses capybara.
It worked on another machine but when I switched machine and installed ruby and bundled and ran it on the new machine I got:

````
me/service.rb:115:in
`connect_until_stable': unable to connect to chromedriver 127.0.0.1:9515 (Selenium::WebDriver
::Error::WebDriverError)```   

Trying to look at the version of chrommedriver gives me this:

    chromedriver -v

/home/michael/.rbenv/versions/2.4.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/nokogiri-1.6.8/lib/nokogiri/xml/document.rb:44: warning: constant ::Fixnum is deprecated
/home/michael/.rbenv/versions/2.4.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/webdrivers-2.4.0/lib/webdrivers/chromedriver.rb:19:in `block in newest_version': undefined method `[]' for nil:NilClass (NoMethodError)```

Error seems to be:

    chromedriver.rb:19:in `block in newest_version': undefined method `[]' for nil:NilClass (NoMethodError)

I also get:

$ sudo apt-get install chromedriver
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Package chromedriver is not available, but is referred to by another package.
This may mean that the package is missing, has been obsoleted, or
is only available from another source

E: Package 'chromedriver' has no installation candidate
````

Comment: webdrivers 2.4 is over two years old - upgrade to a more current release

Comment: good idea. I wonder why i am picking up the older version when I didn't specifiy version (which i now changed). is this something about how this gem is set up?  I bundle daily at least when working

Comment: or do major gem version updates (like major version number NOT get picked up once I have an existing lock file or something perhaps?

Comment: They should get picked up if no version is specified (and no other gem you're using specifies a dependency version requirement). Check your gemfile.lock for references to `webdrivers` to see what else (if anything) specifies it as a requirement.